# Is usage of Default parameters healthy habit or a bad one?

Tags: c++

When should we use **default parameters**? What is the proper syntax and where should they not be used? Is using them regularly a good or a bad habit? Do they affect efficiency?

Comment: Refer to this site. Very clear explanation. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/

Comment: It's normal. If you don't want to use default parameter. You have to override functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only case I can think of where it affects efficiency would be when you include something big as a default parameter but it's not used by any of the callers. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(std::ostream& out=std::cout) {
    out << "foo";
}
```

If none of the callers use the default parameter, and the rest of the program doesn't need `<iostream>`  then it will have been included in vain, increasing the executable size (and compilation time which may or may not matter much).

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax may be found in any C++ reference, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79.aspx. They should never have any efficiency impact. As for usage hints, as with everything else it depends on specific case. They may make things cleared or more complicated.
One more thing worth mentioning - one should be careful with default parameters in virtual functions, since their values are resolved based on the static type, which can be unexpected.

Comment: Let's not call MSDN a C++ reference.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a parameter is specified only in the **declaration** of a (member) function, like so:

```
void fun(int value = 0);
```

Note that only the final parameters in a parameter-list may have default-values. E.g. the following is forbidden:

```
void fun(int v1 = 0, int v2);
```

When the function is defined somewhere else, the default value must be omitted.

```
void fun(int value)
{ 
    cout << value << '\n'; // will print 0 when nothing was passed by the user
}
```

They do **not** have runtime-overhead in any way, as the compiler will add this value to the function-call when the user has not specified it. Use them only when a certain default behavior is intuitive.

It can sometimes serve as an alternative to function overloading. The effect of the example above could also have been achieved by

```
void fun();
void fun(int value);
```

But this means you'd have to implement `fun` twice (where `fun()` just calls `fun(0)`).